# HTML how to remove nested lists?

Tags: html, sanitization

How would I go about sanitizing nested lists away once a user submits some HTML markup.

The list is created with execCommand('insertUnorderedList',false,null)
For some reason, firefox will nest lists when this is used on a line within a li while other browsers simply remove the list (Which is what I want).
I would like to remove the nesting to prevent browser inconsistencies with the submitted html.

example:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to remove the inner ul to get

```
<ul>
  <li>
  </li>
</ul>
```

EDIT: This is user input I need to sanitize.

Comment: You get a text editor and open the html file, then you remove it.

Comment: This is user input I need to sanitize.

Comment: How user put the input?

Comment: ExecCommand(insertUnorderedlist) Nest loops but ONLY in firefox. I wish to fix this so its consistent with other browsers.

Comment: can you please rewrite your question? like what have you done and what your using

Comment: Updated. I'm not really sure how to clarify as all I want is to be able to clear a string of nested lists. Is there anything else you need to know?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('li ul').remove();
})
```

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.